# Importing 200k table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Everytime I try to import a 200k table I am getting this

## 2006 - MySQL server has gone away

I have changed all the times and everything I don't understand

```
    # The MySQL server
[wampmysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 64M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
basedir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17
log-error=c:/wamp/logs/mysql.log
datadir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/data
```

Comment: how are you importing? what is a 200k table?

Comment: a user table I am importing it in phpmyadmin on localhost with wamp

Comment: you say you have 'changed all the times', but none of the variables you pasted have anything to do with mysql timeouts - look here: http://club.orbisius.com/howto/web-development/change-mysqls-wait_timeout-interactive_timeout-variables/

Comment: you decided in 30 seconds that a link about preventing your problem from occurring makes no sense? you can edit my.cnf all you damn well want but if you don't change the values you need to change you may as well be mashing your face against the keyboard.

Comment: it says default is 8 hours